# How does Wolfram's Image Identification Project work?

Tags: image-recognition, deep-learning, classification

Wolfram Language Image Identification Project launched an [Image Identify site](https://www.imageidentify.com/) demo which returns the top predicted tags for the photos.

How does it work, briefly? I mean what type of learning vision technologies are used to analyze, recognize and understand the content of an image?

Comment: It doesn't work properly for all  [Image](https://www.imageidentify.com/public/prd/result/0/n/i/v/5/t/8/t/9/k/x/7/r/preview.jpeg?v=1.13&t=1471625377). I inserted a picture of a nuclear explosion then this showed up

Comment: And also this [image](https://www.imageidentify.com/public/prd/result/1/q/9/q/2/v/2/3/x/d/f/2/1/preview.jpeg?v=1.13&t=1471625738) , its actually a world map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageIdentify project uses the highly automated "[superfunctions](https://www.wolfram.com/algorithmbase/)" and as part of Wolfram Language API integration. It relies on a complex collection of meta-algorithms and built-in '[knowledge](http://www.wolfram.com/knowledgebase/)'. It has a built-in classifier trained from a large dataset using [Wolfram Data Framework](http://www.wolfram.com/data-framework/) (WDF). However the main classifier is based on the deep neural networks.

Source: [How the Wolfram Language Image Identification Project Works](https://www.imageidentify.com/about/how-it-works)

The algorithm isn't perfect and misidentification are more likely to be caused by 'irrelevant objects repeatedly being in training images for a particular type of object'.

You can read more at [Wolfram Language Artificial Intelligence: The Image Identification Project](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2015/05/wolfram-language-artificial-intelligence-the-image-identification-project/).